Can I screw a sagging gutter to the fascia?
A branch fell on my roof and it landed on my gutter.

Because of this, the water is now pooling at one end instead of flowing to the drain. It seems that the branch bent the end of the gutter, so it's not tight against the fascia board anymore.


How do I fix this? Can I just screw the end of the gutter that is hanging into the fascia board?
Thank you!

I would get another bracket and use that near the end to pull up the gutter.  The end of the gutter might just be thin steel/material and just a screw might pull out, if there is a place to put a screw.

Start out by re-crimping the gutter end plate to the back of the gutter. That seam has been pulled apart. Squeeze it back together with a pair of vice grips or channel locks. You will then want to remove the existing caulk and re caulk the entire end plate. Then get a new bracket and install it at the end of the gutter to support it. It's important to support the front of the gutter or it will eventually droop back down, don't just screw the back into the fascia. If you can't find the bracket at your home store, move the one shown further toward the end until you find one.

Your gutter is already screwed to the fascia. Many times.
Either add a bracket similar to the one in the photo an inch or two from the end, or just move that one if the resulting span doesn't seem to get too long.
